# tensorflow: what's wrong with my .tfrecords file?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Today I make a `.tfrecords` file with my images. The width of the image is 2048 and the height is 1536. All the images are almost 5.1GB, but when I use it to make `.tfrecords`, it;s almost 137 GB! More importantlt, when I use it to train, I get an error like `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY`.
Here is the error:

```
Total memory: 10.91GiB
Free memory: 10.45GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Graphics Device, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1034] failed to alloc 68705845248 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 68705845248
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1034] failed to alloc 61835259904 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 61835259904
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1034] failed to alloc 68705845248 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 68705845248
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1034] failed to alloc 68705845248 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 68705845248
.........
```

I use the smallest batch_size, but it's still wrong. Does anyone know why? Is there something wrong with my `tfrecords` file?
The code that I make `tfrecords` with is here:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import os.path
from PIL import Image   
train_file = 'train.txt' 
name = 'trainxx'  
output_directory = './tfrecords'
resize_height = 1536 
resize_width = 2048    
def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))    
def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))        
def load_file(examples_list_file):
    lines = np.genfromtxt(examples_list_file, delimiter=" ", dtype=[('col1', 'S120'), ('col2', 'i8')])
    examples = []
    labels = []
    for example, label in lines:
        examples.append(example)
        labels.append(label)
    return np.asarray(examples), np.asarray(labels), len(lines)  
def extract_image(filename, resize_height, resize_width):
    image = cv2.imread(filename)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (resize_height, resize_width))
    b, g, r = cv2.split(image)
    rgb_image = cv2.merge([r, g, b])
    return rgb_image    
def transform2tfrecord(train_file, name, output_directory, resize_height, resize_width):
    if not os.path.exists(output_directory) or os.path.isfile(output_directory):
        os.makedirs(output_directory)
    _examples, _labels, examples_num = load_file(train_file)
    filename = output_directory + "/" + name + '.tfrecords'
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename)
    for i, [example, label] in enumerate(zip(_examples, _labels)):
        print('No.%d' % (i))
        image = extract_image(example, resize_height, resize_width)
        print('shape: %d, %d, %d, label: %d' % (image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2], label))
        image_raw = image.tostring()
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
            'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image_raw),
            'height': _int64_feature(image.shape[0]),
            'width': _int64_feature(image.shape[1]),
            'depth': _int64_feature(image.shape[2]),
            'label': _int64_feature(label)
        }))
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()    
def disp_tfrecords(tfrecord_list_file):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([tfrecord_list_file])
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
            'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'depth': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
        }
    )
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
    # print(repr(image))
    height = features['height']
    width = features['width']
    depth = features['depth']
    label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    resultImg = []
    resultLabel = []
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
        for i in range(21):
            image_eval = image.eval()
            resultLabel.append(label.eval())
            image_eval_reshape = image_eval.reshape([height.eval(), width.eval(), depth.eval()])
            resultImg.append(image_eval_reshape)
            pilimg = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(image_eval_reshape))
            pilimg.show()
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
        sess.close()
    return resultImg, resultLabel   
def read_tfrecord(filename_queuetemp):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename_queuetemp])
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
            'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'depth': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
        }
    )
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
    # image
    tf.reshape(image, [256, 256, 3])
    # normalize
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) * (1. / 255) - 0.5
    # label
    label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)
    return image, label   
def test():
    transform2tfrecord(train_file, name, output_directory, resize_height, resize_width)  
    img, label = disp_tfrecords(output_directory + '/' + name + '.tfrecords')  
    img, label = read_tfrecord(output_directory + '/' + name + '.tfrecords') 数
    print label      
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Please post the code you use to make the tfrecord files

Comment: I already add my code . But I think it is ok because last time I use it to make tfrecords and the training net can run perfectly .

Answer (score 3):

#### Why has your dataset grown in size

I didn't go through all your code, but I think I found the reason for the explosion in size of your dataset.

Your conversion process looks like this:

1. Get the filenames list
2. Open the image file and reorder the channels
3. Process the image file (rescaling)
4. Write out the data bytes as a string in the .tfrecord file **<-- the problematic point**

Image files are normally compressed. Either lossy or lossless, they are stored in a space-efficient way. You're throwing that efficiency away when you decode the image and save the raw bytes as (uncompressed) text.

#### Why is your code eating up your host RAM

**Note:** I don't know how your input pipeline is set up so I'm making some assumptions here, but I believe I'm getting them right.

The problem here is that, thanks to your decoded image in the tfrecord file, every example you have is rather big in size. When you set up an input pipeline, data is read and queued so that further stages of the pipeline can process it. My idea is that your examples queue gets so big that goes out of memory, because of the size of each single example.

#### What a typical .tfrecord conversion pipeline looks like

There is a simple change you need to make to fix your problem: storing the *raw data of the **compressed** file* in your .tfrecord and then decode directly in Tensorflow.
The process should look as follows:

1. Get the filenames list
2. Open the binary file and read out its content *as a byte string*:

   ```
   with(my_image_filename, 'rb') as fp:
       raw_image = fp.read()
   ```
3. Write the `raw_image` byte string to the .tfrecord file
4. In your Tensorflow input pipeline, you'll read the 'raw_image' byte string tensor and feed it to `tf.image.decode_image()` or one of its more specific variants.

This way, you won't store anywhere the decoded image until you actually need it, so your queues will stay a reasonable size and your tfrecord file too.

#### Other notes on your setup

You're mixing OpenCV and Tensorflow, but this is not necessary. Tensorflow has all you need to convert your dataset to .tfrecord files first and decoded images afterwards and it's IMO much simpler to just stick to Tensorflow's API.
[Here's the guide on how to set the conversion and the input pipeline](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data), which shows the "typical .tfrecord conversion pipeline" I described above, plus a few more tricks if you have other needs (like reading the filenames from the .csv file).

Comment: Thank you very much ! And I will try it later . And here is some other problem ,when I train that tfrecords file, sometimes I get an error in this line in my training code: " _, loss_value,step = sess.run([train_op, loss,global_step], feed_dict={image_holder: image_batch,label_holder : label_batch})" It said this line can not pass . And an other problem is when I run training code ,my computer will stuck and must be restarted

Comment: Please open a new question for these problems describing them in detail (and posting the code and the full error message+traceback), it's impossible to solve them only from this information.